# Trying to filter data by highest number of certain variable R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, grouping

I currently have a dataset (languages) of countries, the common languages spoken in each country and the number of people that speak each languages (langCountryPop). I would like to alter my data so that within each country group I can order langCountryPop in decreasing order. I am essentially trying to extract from each country, what the most spoken language is within each country and only have that data to look at.

This is what my data currently looks like
[image]

Here is an expected output for the first country within the dataset:

```
languages = data.frame("country" = rep("Andorra", 5), "lang" = c("Catalan","Spanish", "French", "Portuguese", "English"), "langCountryPop" = c(31000, 24600, 2400, 2100, 770))
```

I'm not sure how to repeat this for the entire dataset.

This was my attempt:

```
x = lang %>% select(country, lang, langCountryPop) %>% group_by(country) %>% sort(-lang$langCountryPop)
```

Any suggestions to go about doing this with my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need a `group_by` here, and instead of `sort`, we use `arrange`.  Also, the `.$`would extract the whole column breaking the group attributes

```
library(dplyr)
lagn2 <- lang %>% 
   select(country, lang, langCountryPop) %>% 
   arrange(country, desc(langCountryPop))
```

---

If we need to get the `max` row, we can use `slice_max`

```
lang %>%
      group_by(country) %>%
       slice_max(langCountryPop)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to filter you could use:

```
df %>% group_by(country) %>% filter(langCountryPop==max(langCountryPop))
```

Where `df` is your original data.